# How to connect input filed, button, and function JS

Tags: javascript, html

i am learning JS right now, and I don't know how to connect input filed, button, and function. In currently code if I run it i get result of specific string which is in code, so i want to enter random string in input field, and when i click on button get result of that input string.

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="String">

<p>Click the "Try it" button</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
 function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

    let l = str.length;
    let k = 0, row, column;
    row = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(l));
    column = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(l));

    if (row * column < l)
    {
        row = column;
    }

    let s = new Array(row);
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        s[i] = new Array(column);
        for (let j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            s[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
       
    // convert the string into grid
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (let j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            if(k < str.length)
                s[i][j] = str[k];
            k++;
        }
    }

    // Printing the grid
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (let j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            if (s[i][j] == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            document.write(s[i][j]);
        }
        document.write("</br>");
    }
}
 
  let str = "GEEKSFORGEEKS";
  gridStr(str);

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Now, you have written unnessesary code there.

```
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Any String" id="str-to-grid">
    <br>
    <button onClick="stringToGrid()">Try It</button>
    <p id="grid-placeholder"></p>
    <script>
        const Input = document.getElementById("str-to-grid")
        const Placeholder = document.getElementById("grid-placeholder")
        function stringToGrid() {
            //first, let's determine the number of rows and columns we can arrange
            //Usually, in grid, x = y, meaning sqrt(length)
            var dimension = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Input.value.length))

            //Now let's arrange our string:
            var GridView = []
            for ( let stringPtr = 0, dimensionPtr = 0; stringPtr < Input.value.length; stringPtr++)
            {
                GridView.push(Input.value[stringPtr])
                if ( (dimensionPtr + 1)%dimension === 0 )
                {
                    GridView.push("<br />")
                }
                dimensionPtr++;
            }
            Placeholder.innerHTML = GridView.join("")
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

What this code does is everytime you clicked the button, the placeholder
and the value is taken, and the dimension of the grid is calculated to the upperbound square of the length of the string.

Then is a seperate array, each of the string item is placed, and when the row
ends, a br tag is added. this way, a grid view can be created

Comment: @DevMayuhk do you have idea how can i after result of this code get a result of sum every character by that column

Comment: for example string=nemanaili, result of this code is then nem/ana/ili how can i now do nai/eni/mai in same row

Answer (score 0):

This is the improved code: (it will work)

```
    <input type="text" id="myText" value="String">

<p>Click the "Try it" button</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
 function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

    let l = str.length;
    let k = 0, row, column;
    row = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(l));
    column = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(l));

    if (row * column < l)
    {
        row = column;
    }

    let s = new Array(row);
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        s[i] = new Array(column);
        for (let j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            s[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
       
    // convert the string into grid
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (let j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            if(k < str.length)
                s[i][j] = str[k];
            k++;
        }
    }

    // Printing the grid
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (let j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            if (s[i][j] == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            document.write(s[i][j]);
        }
        document.write("</br>");
    }
}
 
  let str = "GEEKSFORGEEKS";
  gridStr(str);

</script>
```

Comment: You should go into a little detail about what you've changed, and why.

Comment: But still when i run program i get result of "GEEKSFORGEEKS" not what i put in the input field...

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you want to do?

Comment: When i put in let str = myText; i get result of string not this "SQUARE CODE"

Comment: @NemanjaIlic So you want to apply the grid function to the string in the input field?

Comment: I want to put in input field random string and get result of this sqaure code which is working,

Comment: @DevMayukh yes grid function

Comment: I solve problem, thank you, I put let str instead of let x and now function is doing what it is supposed to do